# Calculating a New Variable

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code and am looking to create a results column that calculates the difference between the FCT_MAX_CHARGES and CPT_MAX_CHARGES variables. I'm looking for a code that would produce the CPT_FCT DELTA column in the desired table below.

```
USE EMTCQIData

SELECT CONC.[ID Number] as FIN, CONC.table,

   CASE
          WHEN CONC.table like '%level 5%' THEN '99285' 
          WHEN CONC.table like '%level 4%' THEN '99284'

   END FCT_MAX,

   CASE
          WHEN CONC.table like '%level 5%' THEN $200 
          WHEN CONC.table like '%level 4%' THEN $100

   END FCT_MAX_CHARGES,

   CPT.CPT,

   CASE
          WHEN CPT.CPT like '99285%' THEN $200
          WHEN CPT.CPT like '99284' THEN $100

   END CPT_MAX_CHARGES

FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT 


                          Expected Results
ID | FCT_MAX| FCT_MAX_CHARGGES| CPT   | CPT_MAX_CHARGES| CPT_FCT DELTA
 1    99284     200             99284       100              100
```

Comment: Copy the 2 case statements to a new column and put a minus sign between them?

Comment: What variables? There aren't any in your SQL. Variables start with a `@`. Can you try to explain your goal again? Sample data and expected results will really help.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu . Sorry about the confusion. The sample data looks exactly like the expected results table above except that I want to add the CPT_FCT_DELTA, which calculates difference between the FCT_MAX_Charges and CPT_MAX _CHARGES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in another expression at the same scope, but one way to work around that is to perform the first set of expressions at another level, like a CTE or subquery:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    CONC.[ID Number] as FIN, 
    CONC.table,
    CASE
      WHEN CONC.table like '%level 5%' THEN '99285' 
      WHEN CONC.table like '%level 4%' THEN '99284'
    END AS FCT_MAX,
    CASE
      WHEN CONC.table like '%level 5%' THEN $200 
      WHEN CONC.table like '%level 4%' THEN $100
   END AS FCT_MAX_CHARGES,
   CPT.CPT,
   CASE
     WHEN CPT.CPT like '99285%' THEN $200
     WHEN CPT.CPT like '99284' THEN $100
   END AS CPT_MAX_CHARGES
   FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT
)
SELECT 
  FIN,
  [table],
  FCT_MAX,
  CPT,
  FCT_MAX_CHARGES,
  CPT_MAX_CHARGES,
  CPT_FCT DELTA = FCT_MAX_CHARGES - CPT_MAX_CHARGES
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ah this was actually very simple, the following code worked:

```
SELECT FIN, Clinical, FCT_MAX, FCT_MAX_CHARGES, CPT, CPT_CHARGES, (FCT_MAX_CHARGES - CPT_CHARGES) AS DELTA
```